# What is the unit of measurment for media duration in MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, metadata, media, duration

One can use

```
 String MediaMetadataRetriver.extractMetadata(int key);
```

with

```
 key = MediaMetadataRetriver.METADATA_KEY_DURATION
```

to extract the media duration.

This function returns a String, but there is no documentation regarding the format or unit of measurement this string represents.
I would assume it is an integer in *ms*, but the rest of MediaMetadataRetriever's apis uses *us*.

So what is the unit for duration? Do you think the lack of specification is intentional or a bug?

Comment: The unit is millisecound

Answer (score 14):

See this

```
  long durationMs = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
                    long duration = durationMs / 1000;
                    long h = duration / 3600;
                    long m = (duration - h * 3600) / 60;
                    long s = duration - (h * 3600 + m * 60);
                    String durationValue;
                    if (h == 0) {
                       durationValue = String.format(
                       activity.getString(R.string.details_ms), m, s);
                       } else {
                            durationValue = String.format(
                            activity.getString(R.string.details_hms), h, m, s);
                         }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because extractMetadata can return a null you need to wrap this call in a check:

```
int duration = 0;
String dur = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
if (dur != null) {
    duration = Integer.parseInt(dur);
}
mDuration = duration;
long h = duration / 3600;
long m = (duration - h * 3600) / 60;
long s = duration - (h * 3600 + m * 60);
```

(from http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbd47da0af79604fb4a67/android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever?tag=dragonfly)

Answer (score 1):

The output of the extraction is `String`, you need to parse into `long`. And you can handle like that to have formated duration:

```java
public static String formatDurationLongToString() {
        String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long timeInMillisecond = Long.parseLong(time)
        return String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeInMillisecond),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillisecond) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeInMillisecond) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
    }
```